# How to connect two different Bluetooth headsets to one Android phone?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-audio, bluetooth-pairing

I can connect to two devices, but only one is capable of being active at any given time. The reason we want them connected "actively" is singing together on apps like Smile and StarMaker.

I have tried multiple apps without any luck.

How to actively connect two different Bluetooth headphones to one Android phone? Does anyone know of an app that works or some code I can run on a Schok V55?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Android OS doesn't provide a means of playing audio on two different bluetooth devices at the same time.  If both devices happen to be Samsung and produced within the past 5 years, as of the Galaxy S8 they have a feature called [Dual audio](https://www.samsung.com/latin_en/support/mobile-devices/how-can-i-use-dual-audio-to-share-media-on-multiple-devices/) that provides exactly what you need.

> You can share a video or music with a friend without having to physically share a pair of earbuds. This provides a great way to compromise between different needs using two headsets with two varied volume levels connected to a single Galaxy device.

Outside of that, you can get an external USB-C Bluetooth adapter that supports it.  [Such as this one](https://a.co/d/hUS6mbm)

Comment: While the external USB-C adapter supports multiple Bluetooth audio sinks, your android phone won't connect to the external Bluetooth adapter because it already has its own internal Bluetooth adapter. (Ask me how I know )